# Unable to insert a new password into pass (the standard unix password manager)

Tags: unix, passwords, password-storage

I am trying to insert a new password to pass (passwordstore.org), but I am receiving the following error:

```
➜  GitHub git:(master) ✗ pass insert platform-name
Enter password for platform-name:
Retype password for platform-name:
gpg: error retrieving 'xxx@gmail.com' via WKD: Syntax error in URI
gpg: xxx@gmail.com: skipped: Syntax error in URI
gpg: [stdin]: encryption failed: Syntax error in URI
Password encryption aborted.
```

Comment: Shouldn't be there indeed